# Чтение элемента из типизированного файла

Tags: delphi-xe7

```
Type    
    mass = array [0..8] of string[255];
    FTOtdel = file of mass;
var
M:mass;
L_sring:string;

procedure ....;
var i;integer;
begin
...
reset(f2);
seek(f2,i);
read(f2,L_string);
...
end;
```

Так вот, ошибка в чтении из файла, перепробовал многие варианты, ну не пойму я как прочитать строчку из него, все он крашит. **Собственно мне нужно прочитать элемент из массива, по найденной позиции в строчке.**

Comment: А как вы _записывали_ данные в этот файл?

Comment: теперь 2 вопроса, как еще и записать...

Comment: Ну, вы читаете из файла, причём ваш код надеется найти там определённую структуру. Понятно, что если такой структуры там нет, прочитается что-то другое.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, тогда займусь сначала созданием, если проблема не исчезнет, или не решу, вернусь сюда.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте не заморачивался с типизированными файлами, а взял бы просто какой-нибудь `TextFile` и читал бы из него по 9 строк.

Comment: Просто такая идея мне пришла в первые при работе с 'combobox', поэтому так сейчас пытаюсь сделать а переделывать сейчас уже немного поздно, ночь, голова не варит,и просто устал.

Comment: Лучше делать всё с утра, поверьте! :)

Comment: А можно подробнее об этом в лс, я немного не понял идеи.

Comment: Дело в том, что мне уже в падлу 4 дня подряд с утра пытаться сдать этот гребанный курсач! Постоянно учитель докапывается, а сегодня сказал сделаешь это, и гуляй.

Comment: Ну, лс тут нету, а в чат кажется пускают только начиная с какой-то величины кармы.

Comment: Смотрите. Идея в том, что вы выделяете отдельную процедуру чтения, в которой читаете из текстового файла строки по одной. В цикле. Пакуете в массив или список или что там полагается, и возвращаете из процедуры.

Comment: это печально...а можно ли связаться с вами по vk, или другой службе?

Comment: Лучше всего здесь, потому что у меня не всегда будет время ответить, а тут может ответит кто-то другой.

Comment: var i;integer; - это опечатка при копировании? Должно быть двоеточие.